# How do I get the linksys WUSB6300 wireless adapter to work on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to install the driver for Linksys WUSB6300 following this post:

[How do I get the linksys WUSB6300 wireless adapter to work on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux)

However when I run `make` I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from include/net/ip.h:31:0,
                 from /home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_br_ext.c:24:
include/net/route.h: In function ‘ip_route_output’:
include/net/route.h:127:3: error: missing initializer for field ‘flowic_iif’ of ‘struct flowi_common’ [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
   .flowi4_tos = tos,
   ^
In file included from include/net/net_namespace.h:12:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:43,
                 from include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h:26,
                 from include/linux/if_arp.h:27,
                 from /home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_br_ext.c:23:
include/net/flow.h:24:6: note: ‘flowic_iif’ declared here
  int flowic_iif;
      ^
In file included from include/net/ip.h:31:0,
                 from /home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_br_ext.c:24:
include/net/route.h:128:3: error: missing initializer for field ‘flowic_scope’ of ‘struct flowi_common’ [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
   .daddr = daddr,
   ^
In file included from include/net/net_namespace.h:12:0,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:43,
                 from include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h:26,
                 from include/linux/if_arp.h:27,
                 from /home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_br_ext.c:23:
include/net/flow.h:27:7: note: ‘flowic_scope’ declared here
  __u8 flowic_scope;
       ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/core/rtw_br_ext.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/balazs/Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-67-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: First thing to do is install a supported Ubuntu kernel.  Support for 3.16, 3.19, and 4.2 kernels ended in late July see [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Desktop) to see how to update to the 4.4 kernel series

Comment: And after you install a 4.4 kernel, check here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340769

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, I have updated the kernel to 4.4 and followed the steps on the forum, however I get some error at: sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install

`Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=4.4.0-040400-generic KVER=4.4.0-040400-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.3.14 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-040400-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.14/build/make.log for more information.
make: *** [build] Error 10`

Comment: Please consult the log: `cat  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.14/build/make.log` and paste the contents here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Did all the steps leading up to the error go without error or warning?

Comment: Yes, all the steps went fine without error/warning. Here is the log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23389436/

Comment: I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I still have a problem: the connection keeps dropping off every now and then. The wifi works fine under windows. First I figured out that it works again fine for a while if I restart Ubuntu. I have also figured that if I take out the wifi adapter and put into a different USB slot it works also for some time. But it still goes down randomly. Any idea as to what could cause the problem?

Comment: @BalázsFehér +1 for this problem, I am also on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the same card (WUSB6300), it works flawlessly for a time then randomly cuts out. It might only be cutting out when my computer goes to sleep I haven't verified this yet.

Comment: Never mind, definitely happens at random and not just when waking from sleep. Unplugging and replugging in my card fixes it every time, but this is super annoying (and it only works for about 30 minutes max, then cuts out).