# Linksys WUSB 6300 Wireless Adapter Keeps Disconnecting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I followed instruction on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux) to install the driver. The wifi adapter seems to be working. However, it keeps dropping wifi connections and re-connecting every few minutes.

My machine has dual boots, Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 10. And Windows 10 never drops the wifi. Doesn't seem to be the adapter or my home wifi issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git

git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812AU-driver-5.2.9

sudo dpkg -i gord-rtl8812au-dkms_1.0-13_amd64.deb
```

Or install with gdebi package installer

Comment: This gave me `ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.20.8-042008-generic is not supported`. I can't downgrade the kernel because then proper support for my i7 9700k fails.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer was outdated due to kernel updates. This solution works for Mint 19.1 based on Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel version 4.20.8.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git

git clone https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au

cd rtl8812au

make
sudo make install
```

If you are using NetworkManager (default in Mint) need to add this to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (might be present by default, mine was)

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then restart.