# Lubuntu Linksys WUSB6400M Wifi USB adapter driver help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, lubuntu

My [[Linksys WUSB6400M] Wifi USB adapter](https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WUSB6400M/) for my desktop won't connect to wifi because I suspect it needs driver installation. When I type `lusb` into the terminal, it shows `Bus 008 Device 003: ID 13b1:0043 Linksys`.
I plan to connect an Ethernet cable and try methods I found on the internet such as installing [B43 firmware](http://www.itadmintools.com/2011/11/getting-your-linksys-wireless-adapter.html) and installing the [driver for a Linksys WUSB6300](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux) since the two models sound similar. Does anyone have any suggestions or know how to install the correct driver for my 6400M so I can connect to wifi. Also I'm running Lubuntu 18.04

1st Edit: Well, I've tried both of those methods and they didn't work

2nd Edit: I'm convinced the drivers don't exist and have given up.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it running on ubuntu 16.04 by installing rtl8822bu driver from https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8822bu

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found the solution, this works for Linksys WUSB6300 and Dlink DWA-182 rev.C:

## Setup Wireless USB On Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 thru 20.04

Make sure USB wireless device not inserted

1. Update the system:
   `$ sudo apt update`
2. Install required packages:
   `$ sudo apt install git && build-essential`
3. Download the driver:
   `$ sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au`
4. Go to the directory:
   `$ cd rtl8812au`
5. Do the next commands consecutively:
   `$ sudo make clean`
   `$ sudo make`
   `$ sudo make uninstall`
   `$ sudo make install`

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

-Persists reboots
-Works with dlink dwa-182 and linksys WUSB6300

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it, it's tested WITH Ubuntu AND Mint, both are working perfectly!!!!!

ACCURATE DEVICE INFO : https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/Linksys_WUSB6400M
WORKING DEVICE DRIVER : https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU