# AC1200 Wireless adapter in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, connection, 19.10

I did the following in a terminal to get a AC1200 Linksys Wireless adapter to work on my Ubuntu 19.10 install:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
```

This process went through without errors and install was completed.  However, my wireless USB adapter still doesn't work. I ran `lsusb` in terminal and my wireless adapter was listed as

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 13b1:003f Linksys WUSB6300 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

I then ran the following, and it simply returned the command line prompt

```
modinfo 8812au | egrep -i 'versi|filen|003f'
sudo modprobe -v 8812au
iwconfig
iwlist chan
```

When I opened my network setting for WiFi, I received the following:

> No WiFi Adapter found
>   Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged in and turned on

I also tried to get it to work by installing `ndiswrapper`, but that didn't work either.  I have researched this and have tried numerous things I found, but nothing seems to work. I know this has been answered before, but the answers all indicate the above procedure.  Any help is appreciated as I am new to Ubuntu, but have run Red Hat linux prior to its shifting to Fedora.

Comment: I apologize that the commands all ran together.  I am new at this and will do better next time.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux and use the dkms installation instructions,

Comment: I tried several ways, finally was to resolve it with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312324/797737) worked.

Answer (score 2):

---

For Linksys WUSB6300 do this:

Make sure USB wireless device not inserted

1. Update the system:
   `$ sudo apt update`
2. Install required packages:
   `$ sudo apt install git && build-essential`
3. Download the driver:
   `$ sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au`
4. Go to the directory:
   `$ cd rtl8812au`
5. Do the next commands consecutively:
   `$ sudo make clean`
   `$ sudo make`
   `$ sudo make uninstall`
   `$ sudo make install`

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

-Persists reboots
-Works with dlink dwa-182 and linksys WUSB6300