# How to install dwa 181 usb wifi adaptor's driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, d-link

I am trying to install my dwa 181 wifi usb adaptor's driver on ubuntu but it's not working, i have downloaded the official linux driver on d-link website https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-181-US and i spent 7 hours searching on different websites how to install the driver but without any result.

So, there's something i can do to install the driver?

-- edit --

results from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2001:331e D-Link Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 087: ID 12d1:108a Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. POT-LX1
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

results from `mokutil --sb-state`:

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Probable answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312297/usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts/1312324#1312324  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ok i modified the question and i have also tried the probable answer but it's not working because whatever i use make or dkms, make fail giving some errors

Comment: What errors, exactly? If the output is lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: This is what the terminal give when i run "sudo make" https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gSkYxkFXxv/

Comment: And you are quite sure this is the file you acquired by git at the link I gave and not a leftover from a previous unsuccessful attempt? If you have any previous attempts, please delete them first.

Comment: this is the same result of many files that i have downloaded online and the original driver on the d-link website

Comment: Is this Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: it is ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Please delete *all* previous attempts now and git clone the version I suggested from git. I just tried it and it 'makes' without any errors at all on my 5.8.0-41 system.

Comment: it's giving me an error on the first dkms command "Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl88x2bu-5.6.1
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
"

Comment: What do these commands tell us? `sudo modprobe 88x2bu && dmesg | grep 88x2` and also: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: `ric3cir121@ric3cir121:~/Scrivania/rtl88x2bu$ sudo modprobe 88x2bu && dmesg | grep 88x2
modprobe: FATAL: Module 88x2bu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-41-generic
ric3cir121@ric3cir121:~/Scrivania/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dkms status
rtl88x2bu, 5.2.4.4: added
rtl88x2bu, 5.6.1: added`

Comment: In dkms status, we see "added" and not installed, meaning that they did not compile correctly. Let's remove them all: `sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4 --all` and also: `sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.6.1 --all` Then try the git version again from the dkms steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!