# usb wifi (realtek 802.11ac) not recognized by xubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, xubuntu, realtek

I could follow all steps as outlined in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312297/usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

However, this step:

```
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
```

Returns:

```
the directory rtl88x2bu-5.6.1 does not exist
```

Appreciate any help to complete the driver upgrade

Comment: Did you perform the line of `sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}` exactly with the spaces or did that line error out?  Because it doesn't seem like it copied over the source files into the `/usr/src` folder like it was supposed to.  All of those lines in that can be copied and pasted into a terminal.

Comment: Thanks Terrance, I do not get an error,  I re-ran that step and see:

sent 5.05G bytes  received 2.25M bytes  96.28M bytes/sec
total size is 5.04G  speedup is 1.00
as return
yet,  doing the next step today return:
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module> -v <module-version>

Comment: The line of `VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)` is what is used to set the version.  You might want to run that line again from the rtl88x2bu folder that was created when you ran the git command.

Comment: Thank you, Terrance!  That did it,  my WIFI is now working - really appreciate your help!  Have a great weekend, Marc