# xubuntu usb wifi driver lost with recent update

Tags: drivers, kernel, xubuntu

I am running VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
The most recent software update may have disabled my USB wifi driver.
I wanted to re-install the driver as the answer in this Q instructs
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312297/usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts(this worked for me last year).
When repeating those instructions I run into this error:

step: sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
outcome:
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.13.0-27-generic KVER=5.13.0-27-generic src=/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl88x2bu: 5.6.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.6.1/build/make.log for more information.

Q: Appreciate help with updating / re-installing this driver (assuming its not the antenna that went bad)

Comment: This probably means that the driver doesn't build with the 5.13 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I just built the most recent version of the driver in a virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04. My kernel version, as reported by `uname -r` is `5.13.0-39-generic`. I am using an amd64 system. So I would suspect the driver still builds on Ubuntu systems.

However, I noticed your error messages state you are using `5.6.1` as the version of the driver. This version is outdated and not updated anymore. The maintained version is `5.8.7.1` which is the available [here](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/tree/5.8.7.1_35809.20191129_COEX20191120-7777).

Comment: thanks, I switched to mint and resolved that way.  Will try the new Xubuntu soon