# Newbie - Having trouble installing USB WIFI adapter 20.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

Final edit: Solution is linked above. However the "git clone" link has been updated to "https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702" so use that in place.

I have an "QGOO" USB 3.0 dongle which is supposed to work on Linux. It came with a usb stick with drivers. The drivers are zipped in folders, one file of which is a .sh file which I'm reading is supposed to execute the correct commands to install the driver. I've done a ton of searching and I've gotten as far as to right click on these files, and allow it to run as a program. After I do this the cursor spins for several seconds and then nothing. Nothing on reboot. I do not see a terminal after clicking on this .SH files.

I also used the "lsusb" command and confirmed Ubuntu can see the dongle. However it is not lighting up and I have no options regarding wifi. It instantly works and is recognized when plugged into a windows machine.

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2222:1111 MacAlly Mass storage
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm pretty new to ubuntu with only basic knowledge, but I'm generally pretty good on windows machines and trouble shooting. This is a whole other language for me though.

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried:

[usb wifi adapter is not working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312297/usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

I get errors trying to use the dkms commands toward the end. Something about invalid format.

Same here: [How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu)

I'm not a coder or programmer so I'm very basic at this sort of thing.

The last command of the solution provided does not work:

```
dave@MediaCenter:~/88x2bu$ ./install-driver.sh
bash: ./install-driver.sh: No such file or directory
dave@MediaCenter:~/88x2bu$ /install-driver.sh
bash: /install-driver.sh: No such file or directory
dave@MediaCenter:~/88x2bu$ install-driver.sh
install-driver.sh: command not found
dave@MediaCenter:~/88x2bu$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post that lsusb line that identifies the hardware. Very likely it'll need some manually installed drivers but NOT the ones that come with it as those typically are old and/or untested on Ubuntu and often there are better options than running their script.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Doesn't `lsusb` include more than that? We want to see all of the details, especially the usb.id; something like 0bda:b899 or some such.

Comment: @chili555 Done. With some edition info

Comment: Your device is the same as the duplicate and you require the same driver.

Comment: @chili555 The last command "./install-driver.sh" does not work. See the edit

Comment: The GitHub repo mentioned in that answer says it has moved to a new location. I updated the answer there with the updated location, which should have a `install-driver.sh`