# Ho to install AC1300 NANO drivers

Tags: drivers

I think I have the driver files I just dont know how to install them.
I got them from : https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-181-US

I cant figure out what to do .
Ive tried reading it but cant figure it out ive tried looking around yet I cant find anything for D-LINK AC1300 NANO only TP-LINK etc..
Please tell me the commands to install .

lsusb command output :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:331e D-Link Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:571a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?  That driver is too old for modern Ubuntu releases. See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1312324/167850

Comment: this is a fork of ubuntu called linux mint it should be the new ubuntu relase

Comment: edit: it worked thank you!

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic here. You can ask at [linux.se]. But the linked answer still may work.

Comment: i know but its a fork so i just thought it would work i will be swiching t ubuntu anyways very soon and it did work ty