How to install driver for Digma DWA-AC1300E Wifi USB adaptor? on ubuntu 20.4
I purchased a wireless USB adaptor because my operating system, ubuntu 20.04, is no longer detecting my wifi card.
When I purchased it, I thought it would be the type of Wifi USB adaptor that you simply need to plug and it works right away, but when I unpacked it I unfortunately realized that it would require drivers
How do I install the driver?
edit: lsusb gives out
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 30fa:1040 Realtek USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0db0:0076 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 284b:9100 FENGRUN GAMING KEYBOARD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Please attach output of this terminal command: lsusb (after plugging the adapter in)

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 30fa:1040 Realtek USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0db0:0076 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 284b:9100 FENGRUN GAMING KEYBOARD

Try the solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312297/usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts
