# Is there any way to install the WUSB6300 Drivers to a USB?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, internet

Just installed linux for the first time and I want to install the drivers for my adapter but the methods I see require you to connect to the internet on the Computer. Is it possible to install the drivers from a USB instead of having to connect to wifi on the PC?

Comment: Check if you have dkms installed by default "sudo dkms status", if you do then you can download the driver to a USB and then build it on that box. There is no Ubuntu drive for that dongle, you will need to build it and then install it.

Comment: Okay thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

If you have DKMS then you can build and install the driver, otherwise there is no driver for this dongle for Ubuntu. dkms is needed or you cant install the driver:

See answer on this article: [How do I get the linksys WUSB6300 wireless adapter to work on linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux)

Here is a newer driver if the one listed does not work: https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au-5.6.4.2