# Ubuntu 23.04 Wi-Fi keeps losing access to internet but still appears connected

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

I've had Ubuntu 23.04 on my desktop gaming PC for about a month and recently (as in around a week ago) the Wi-Fi has near constantly been "disconnecting". The Wi-Fi icon shows that I'm connected, but it's like no actual data is being sent or received. Another thing is that every now and then, the Wi-FI totally and utterly breaks down. Connecting at all is impossible unless I reboot. When it happened again today I checked journalctl and there was a bunch of errors. I'll post some of the screenshots I took.

The Wi-Fi adapter I'm using is a Linksys WUSB6300 V2 with rtw_8822bu drivers that came already installed in the system, which uses the Linux 6.2.0-20-generic kernel. Many times when the connection goes out journalctl is filled with "timed out to flush queue 3" but when the Wi-Fi drops entirely it has 1 and 3 thrown in there too.

[This is usually what it looks like when the Wi-Fi shuts off entirely. I noticed an interesting "failed to download firmware" error a few times in there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o3or.png)

Some other messages I've noticed are "CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS" which is almost always followed by "timed out to flush queue 3". Another message which sometimes accompanies the flush queue one is "failed to get tx report from firmware" but that only happens every here and there.

[The bottom portion contains the "CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Wbz.png)

Sometimes, the flush out queue error is also accompanied by some "mac power on failed" errors. When **that** happens, I see "timed out to flush queue 1" and "timed out to flush queue 2" alongside the one with 3 in it (which I pointed out above):

[There's also some stuff about idle and ips state. No clue what that could mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjrIE.png)

This whole thing seems to be kinda random. I can go days at a time with no problems, but then all of a sudden it cuts out every 30 seconds followed by having to reboot over and over again. This is the first time I've posted something on here so I apologize if I was bad at writing all this out. I'm hoping I can find some way to fix the problem and I appreciate any and all help! If someone needs a tad bit more info let me know.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I just wanted to confirm that the driver (8822bu) that you're using is the correct driver. [From a related (older) post, I see the OP using a different driver](https://askubuntu.com/q/1358383/32664). Not sure if the diff here is hardware V1 vs V2, but may want to confirm. Finally, a [good discussion regarding the 8822bu driver and those "timed out to flush" messages is here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg233181.html).

Comment: I've actually used the 88x2bu drivers by morrownr before, back in 2022 when I first tried out LInux. Wi-Fi was still kinda buggy, but I never went into the journal to look for flush out queue messages. Pretty sure the 8822bu driver is the correct one though and that it's just hardware difference as the OP seems to go with 8812au drivers, which don't work with the V2. I've tried 'em :)

Comment: Is your firmware file corrupted? `ls -al /usr/lib/firmware/rtw88/rtw8822b_fw.bin` I believe the size is supposed to be 150984. If not, I suggest you reinstall linux-firmware.

Comment: Just checked and the size is indeed 150984. Also, I took a look a the discussion richbl gave a link to, and the flushed out messages seem to be related to NetworkManager scanning for networks. So I went ahead and whipped out journalctl and scanned for networks and lo and behold, it gets filled with "timed out to flush queue 3"